# If is not variable Twig condition

Tags: php, templates, twig, conditional-statements

I need to set some conditions in twig, so i have this:

```
{% if app.session.get('campaignVersion') is not null and is not '4.4d'}
...
{% elseif app.session.get('campaignVersion') is null or '4.4d' %}
...
{% endif %}
```

But i have errors with syntax and logic, maybe it must have an standard operator such as `!=`, what i'm doing wrong? Thx for help.

Comment: BTW, I would make such computation in the controller, leaving you with a more reusable template in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twig is not a human language interpreter :-)

Twig is not able to implicitly know who is the subject in `and is not '4.4d'`.

Try with:

```
{% if app.session.get('campaignVersion') is not null and app.session.get('campaignVersion') != '4.4d' %}
```

Or for better readibility:

```
{% if app.session.get('campaignVersion') not in [null, '4.4d'] %}
```

Comment: `Unexpected token "string" of value "4.4d" ("name" expected)`

Comment: Edited the first example. "is not" takes a test (who begins with a `name` token), not a string. I replaced it by `!=`. Anyway, you should look at the second example.

Answer (score 0):

A % is missing at the end of the first line

Comment: OK, this was a problem, but also i have some problems with logic, or conditions definition...

Comment: I think they are a problem in the second condition of the elseif you said is not null (this is ok) then you just put '4.4d' without saying if: it is or it is not